# why am I getting ERROR: syntax error at end of input?

Tags: postgresql

I am keep getting 'syntax error at end of input' and don't know why.

What I want to do is divide result of disease by result of total with showing condition_id in disease section.

```
select disease.condition_id, (disease::float/total::float) as prevalence
from (
    select condition_id, count(person_id)
    from a.condition
    where condition_id=316139
    group by condition_id
    ) as disease
join (
    select count(distinct person_id) as total
    from a.person
    )as total;
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact fix for your current syntax, but I would phrase this query as a join with an aggregation over the entire tables:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.condition_id = 316139) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT p.person_id) AS prevalence
FROM a.person p
LEFT JOIN a.condition c
    ON p.person_id = c.person_id;
```

Comment: Sadly it's not working properly, it returns 0 where it suppose to give 0.048 and also I want to show condition_id with the prevalence as result. Thanks!

Comment: Your second condition does not make sense, since you hard code condition `316139`.  In any case, please add sample data to your question.

Comment: select (disease::float/total::float) as prevalence from( select (select condition_id, count(person_id) from a.condition_occurrence where condition_id=316139 ) as disease, count(distinct person_id) as total from a.person <- when I run this query it works perfectly fine but when I add condition_id it's keep getting me an error. -> select conditio_id, (disease::float/total::float) as prevalence
  from( select (select condition_id, count(person_id)  from a.condition_occurrence where condition_id=316139 group by condition_id) as disease, count(distinct person_id) as total from a.person) t

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for your error is the missing join condition. The `join` operator requires a join condition (defined using `ON`).

But given the structure of your query I think you don't actually want a inner join, but a `cross join` between the two.

Additionally the expression `disease::float` is trying to cast a complete row to a float value, not a single column. I assume you wanted to alias the count aggregate to something, e.g. `count(person_id) as num_persons`

Using `total::float` is also ambiguous as you have a sub-query alias with that name **and** a column with that name. That is highly confusing, you should avoid that.

```
select disease.condition_id, 
       (disease.num_person::float / total.total::float) as prevalence
from (
    select condition_id, count(person_id) as num_person
    from a.condition
    where condition_id = 316139
    group by condition_id
) as disease
  cross join (
    select count(distinct person_id) as total
    from a.person
  ) as total
```